# Using select with messageformat

Tags: internationalization, icu, messageformat

I am using [MessageFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/messageformatter.formatmessage.php) (part of the `intl` extension) in PHP. The extension uses ICU 4.6.1.

However, the problem isn't with PHP.

I would like to format a piece of string by making a decision on the first token `{0}`:

- When `{0}` is `0`, the text should be `a`
- When it is `1`, the text should be `b`
- For all other cases, the text should be `c`

I understand that this could be done with `plural`, `=0` for the `0` case, but through my testing, it doesn't seem to work, most likely because offsets and custom plurals were introduced in 4.8.

I am thus, trying to accomplish that using `select`:

```
{0, select, 0 {a} other {{0,plural,one{b}other{c}}}}
```

However, for some reason, the message formatter was unable to format the above and returns `false` (couldn't format).

Why is this the case? Is there a problem with my syntax?

---

Quick update: After some digging, it seems that I cannot use select to match values that start with a number. Are there any ways around this?

Another update: Updated to ICU 49.1.2 and `intl` 3.0.0a2. I can now use `=0`, `=1`, etc, but this has stopped working (was working previously):

```
{0}{0, plural, one{a} other{b}}
```

where as this works:

```
{0, plural, one{a} other{b}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to the latest version of `intl` and ICU 49.1.2.

However, once that was done, this would not work:

```
{0}{0, plural, one{a} other{b}}
```

But this worked:

```
{0, plural, =0{a} one{# b} other {# c}}
```

Comment: This smells like abusing plurals though. Won't the translator wonder what on earth is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The `select` argument type is an exact string match. You would need to make sure that you are passing a string argument value, and then have clauses that match. Avoid using plurals for exact case matching, since each locale has its own rules for what `one` means.

The following *should* give you what you want, but I know much more about the format than the PHP implementation.

```
MessageFormatter::formatMessage($locale,
  '{0, select, _0 {a} _1 {b} other {c}}',
  array( "_$value" ))
```